Change width of columns
I am working on this CV template https://www.overleaf.com/5977124985xvtnsqrryfhj#4ae244 and I want to change the width of the columns to be equally distributed (not like it is now). So could anybody please help me figure out how to do so? Thanks in advance.

Please add a short, but compilable test file directly to your question which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

The template seems to be based on altacv class, so you could start having a look to that class code and/or documentation. What is printed as sidebar is actually defined as a \marginpar, so possibly you have to play with \marginparwidth.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I need to make the column with starting with Working experience to be 50% of the page and the column starting with My life philosophy to be the other 50% of the page or that the 2 columns would be equally distributed throughout the page  https://www.overleaf.com/project/66671e2da805f9e019fb447c

@lacobus1983 I tried and look at it but I can't solve the problem either. So If you could help me with it it would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance

Dear Simon, Here's the link to the project https://www.overleaf.com/5977124985xvtnsqrryfhj#4ae244

@Marw Questions on tex.se should be self-sustained to make sure they will remain useful for future users even if the links stop working. Therefore, please include a test document in your question.

Try (replace by) \geometry{left=1.3cm,right=11.2cm,marginparwidth=8.5cm,marginparsep=1.2cm,top=1.25cm,bottom=1.25cm,footskip=2\baselineskip}
